# Sorting Table in a proper order: replacing 3rd and 4th

Tags: list-manipulation, table

I can generate a Table of Following,

```
Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 2.25, 1.25}, {j, 15, 12, -3}], 1]
```

and the output is

```
{{1., 15}, {1., 12}, {2.25, 15}, {2.25, 12}}
```

However, how can I get the following order instead,

```
{{1, 15}, {1, 12}, {2.25, 12}, {2.25, 15}}
```

?

Comment: `Flatten[#, 1] &@GatherBy[tab, Last]`

Comment: @Syed modified a question a bit, I mean the order.

Comment: `Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {j, 15, 12, -3}, {i, 1, 2.25, 1.25}], 1]`

Comment: @Syed Thanks! modified the order!

Comment: `Flatten[MapAt[Reverse, 2]@
  Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 2.25, 1.25}, {j, 15, 12, -3}], 1]`

Comment: `ReplacePart[list, {3 -> list[[4]], 4 -> list[[3]]}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 2.25, 1.25}, {j, 15, 12, -3}], 1];
SubsetMap[Reverse, input, {3, 4}]
```

Or

```
SubsetMap[SortBy[Last], input, {3, 4}]
```

Or

```
Permute[input, {1, 2, 4, 3}]
```

Or

```
Permute[input, Cycles[{{3, 4}}]]
```